# Excluir registro comparando valores entre duas tabelas

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho duas tabelas:

```
produtos
- id_produto

valores
- id_produto
```

`id_produto` seria uma coluna, igual para as duas tabelas.

Eu preciso excluir os registros da tabela **valores**, porém somente aqueles que NÃO estão também na tabela **produtos**.

Ex:

Tenho dois produtos cadastrados, e na tabela **valores** possuí a ID desses dois produtos. Por algum motivo eu apaguei um produto da tabela **produtos**, porém ficou o registro la na tabela **valores**.

Quero apagar esse registro la.

Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Faça um `DELETE` com um `SUB-SELECT`:

```
DELETE FROM valores WHERE id_produto NOT IN (SELECT id_produto FROM produtos);
```

Comment: Não precisa de inner join ai?

Comment: Olá @Wendler não precisa não

Comment: @Wendler não é possível fazer `INNER JOIN` no `DELETE`.